# Int won't show numbers after the comma

Tags: swift, string, int

I want to get from a string to a int. My problem is now that i'll get a int value but it wont show the number after the comma. If the string is -0,23, than the int will print 0.How can i fix this? Please help.

```
let int = (percent_change_24hArray[indexPath.row] as NSString).integerValue
```

Comment: What integer result do you expect if the string is `-0,23`  ?

Comment: -> Don't use NSString in Swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a float, integers don't take numbers after the comma
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/float

Answer (score 2):

You will probably have to use a `NumberFormatter` for that, set up for your locale. In the US, the decimal separator is a period. (".") A comma is considered a delimiter.

Plus, assuming you are in a locale where the decimal separator is a comma, converting to an integer will truncate the part after the decimal separator anyway.

Code like the code below should work:

```
var str = "-0,23"

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")


let aVal = formatter.number(from: str)?.doubleValue
```

(I'm using France's French as the locale since France uses a comma as a decimal separator.)

Note that you need to think carefully about where you numeric strings come from in order to decide how to handle locale. if these are user-entered strings then you should probably use a number formatter with the default locale for the device. That way a European user can use a comma as a decimal separator and a US user can use a period as a decimal separator and both will work.